# Number of booked rooms on a particular date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I store details of all the customers and their checkin and checkout date in an Excel sheet. I want the list of customers staying in the hotel on a particular date in a separate sheet.

Example -- Sheet 1 has below Data

```
Sr.No | Customer Name | Check in | Check out

1 -- kamal -- 2/23/2016 -- 2/25/2015

2 -- abhishek -- 2/26/2016 -- 2/28/2016

3 -- nitn -- 2/24/2016 -- 3/01/2016

4 -- aman -- 3/01/2016 -- 3/03/2016

5 -- vivek -- 3/05/2016 -- 3/06/2016

6 -- harsh -- 3/08/2016 -- 3/09/2016
```

I want to enter any date in sheet 2 like '2/24/2016' and based on the entries in sheet 1 I should get the list/details of customers who are staying in hotel on '2/24/2016'. Based on the above example the output should be:

```
Sr.No -- Customer Name -- Check in -- Check out

1 -- kamal -- 2/23/2016 -- 2/25/2015

2 -- nitn -- 2/24/2016 -- 3/01/2016
```

as Kamal checked in on '2/23/2016' and staying till '2/25/2016' and nitn checked in on 2/24/2016.

Comment: If you tried *various excel operations and macro codes*, you should be able to post at least a couple of those in your question here to show what you've tried, and explain how they didn't work as you need. Please [edit] to do so. Not doing so makes your question sound like the old *Honest, teacher, I did my homework! The dog ate it!*, except more like *Honest! I tried lots of stuff on my own but nothing worked!*.

Comment: read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the most out of help on SO

Comment: Also look into advanced filters.

Comment: I think question is logical. So, people shouldn't down vote the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shown in same sheet, you can easily deploy in sheet2.
***Use this array formula,***

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$D$13,SMALL(IF($C$3:$C$13<=$H$1,IF($D$3:$D$13>=$H$1,ROW($C$3:$D$13)-ROW($C$2))),ROWS($C$3:$C3)),COLUMNS($A$3:A$3)),"")
```

[image]

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula.

Drag and drop `Down` and `Right.`

Comment: When you will use it in `Sheet2`, I suggest you to use `named range`. Named range will help you to make formula easier and neat & clean. Name Sheet1 Sl column data as `SL`, Name comun data as `cusName` as so on...

Comment: Glad to know. You should accept (Tick as green) my answer.